# How to disable href if h6 element has specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to disable href if h6 element has specific text

```
 $('#idtest:contains("123")').remove(Attr('href');)
```

above is what I have tried.

Comment: between "remove" and "Attr" that "(" .. been a while since i touched jquery.. so not sure if that should be there

Comment: So `h6#idtest` has attribute `href`? Seems weird

Comment: @RSR couldn't you just stop the click from following the link instead? If so, you attach a click event handler to the element and if your condition (if statement) resolves to true, fire off the event.preventDefault() method that will prevent the link from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then tell me if works there:

```
if ( $('#idtest:contains("123")') && $('#idtest:contains("123")').html() ) {
  $('a').attr('href', '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
var text = $('#your_id').text();
if(text.includes('teststring')){
    $('#your_id').removeAttr("href");
}
```